Mixed Integer programming reformulation - Proof verification
Consider the following set of constraints that need to be reformulated into a set of MILP constraints.
$$
\begin{cases}
f_1(x) \leq a, \ \text{if } g(x) \leq b, \\
 f_2(x) \leq a, \ \text{if } g(x) > b.  
\end{cases}
$$
Following the  answer, define $d_1$ and $d_2$ such that $d_1, d_2 \in \{0,1\}$ and $d_1+d_2=1$.
When $d_1=1$, we want the first constraint to be satisfied, else it is redundant. So we have
$$
f_1(x)-a \leq M(1-d_1), \  g(x)-b \leq M(1-d_1).
$$
When $d_2=1$, we want the second constraint to be satisfied, else it is redundant. So we have
$$
f_2(x)-a \leq M(1-d_2), \  b+\epsilon - g(x)  \leq M(1-d_2).
$$
We fix $M$ and $\epsilon$ to be very large and very small numbers, respectively. Could you please tell me if this reformulation is correct. Any simplification that I can make here ?

This looks correct to me.
